# Regex: how split string on word with some length

Tags: python, regex

I need to check quantity some words in string and I use

```
len(re.split('[А-Яа-яЁё]{5,}', s))
```

But it works incorrect and to string `'Москва, Вавилова'`
it returns

```
['', ', ', '']
```

What should I change to get

```
['Москва', 'Вавилова']
```

Comment: `s.split(', ')` or `re.findall('[А-Яа-яЁё]{5,}', s)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
re.findall('[А-Яа-яЁё]{5,}', 'Москва,Вавилова')
```

from documentation.

```
re.findall
```

Return all 
non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

```
re.split
```

Split string by the occurrences of pattern.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

Why quantify yourself? Let [Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) do it:

```
from collections import Counter
text = "tata, ohhhhh, tata, oh, tata, ohhhh"
c = Counter ( (len(w.strip()) for w in text.split(",") ))

print(c.most_common())
```

Output:

```
[(4, 3), (2, 1), (5, 1), (6, 1)] # (word-length, count)
```

---

Using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will give you the words as well:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for w in (w.strip() for w in text.split(",")):
    d[len(w)].append(w)

print(d)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, 
            {2: ['oh'], 4: ['tata', 'tata', 'tata'], 5: ['ohhhh'], 6: ['ohhhhh']})
```

but you would have to get the `len()` the list afterwards.